# Append css to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can below jQuery be amended so that instead of appending to the generic .myCss style I can append to the css within the specific div 'myDiv' ?

```
var myDiv= $("#myDiv");
$('<a class=\".newCss\" href=\"#\"></a>').appendTo('.myCss');
```

By append to css I mean the div gets converted from this :

```
<div id="myId" class="myCss">
</div>
```

to this :

```
<div id="myId" class="test">
    <a class="myCss"></a>                                               
</div>
```

Comment: You need to remove the `.` in the `class? attribute and you should not escape `"` inside a `'`-quoted string.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: You can escape `"` within a `'`-quoted string if you like. You don't *have* to, but you can.

Comment: You don't need to remove the `.` from the class name, but it is a pretty weird class name that starts with them. Escaping `"` characters in a string delimited with `'` is wasteful and hard to read, but won't break anything.

Comment: @Quentin: Chances are good that he does not have a class name containing a dot

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Given we can see one in his code, it is certain that he does ;)

Comment: @Quentin he wouldn't be the last coder to forget that only class _selectors_ start with a dot.

Comment: @Quentin: [CSS class names cannot start with or otherwise contain a `.`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: what do you _actually_ mean by "_append to the css_" ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — HTML class names can (although it isn't good practise for them to do so).

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, that's true. If the class is **only** for use with HTML, you could use a dot. Of course, you couldn't use jQuery to find elements with that class name (and probably not add or remove it), as jQuery uses CSS's rules for class names as it uses CSS selectors. But yes, just like `id` is more liberal in HTML, `class` is as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — It seems that [the jQuery selector engine can cope with dots](http://jsfiddle.net/u9NN3/2/). (Still a terrible idea to use them though).

Comment: @Quentin: Interesting. At the cost of not being able to optimize via `querySelectorAll` when available, of course. Sizzle's fast, but it's not as fast as the built-in.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — Maybe it was optimising via qsa and it is a "feature" of Chrome/Opera. This [test case](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/query.html) gave me one result, not zero. I haven't tried IE or Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the selector.

```
$('<a class=\".newCss\" href=\"#\"></a>').appendTo('#myDiv');
```

Alternative, since you have a reference to it already, just pass the jQuery object you created using that selector earlier.

```
var myDiv= $("#myDiv");
$('<a class=\".newCss\" href=\"#\"></a>').appendTo(myDiv);
```

---

Since the question has been rewritten:

1. If you don't want a silly `.` in the class name, don't put one in it
2. If you don't want an href attribute, don't put one in it
3. Make sure the id you use in the HTML matches the id you use in the CSS

Such:

```
var myDiv= $("#myId");
$('<a class="newCss"></a>').appendTo(myDiv);
```

Comment: @gdoron — `#myDiv` **is** a selector.

Comment: @Quentin: You dont need escaping in `'<a class=\".newCss\" href=\"#\"></a>'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<a class="newCss" href="#"></a>').appendTo('#myDiv .myCss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
var myDiv= $("#myDiv");
$('<a class="newCss" href="#"></a>').appendTo(myDiv);
```

Or simply:

```
$('<a class="newCss" href="#"></a>').appendTo('#myDiv');
```

Or

```
$("#myDiv").append('<a class="newCss" href="#"></a>');
```

Or

```
$("#myDiv").html('<a class="newCss" href="#"></a>');
```

**Things Fixed:**

- Removed dot from `class=\".newCss\"`
- Removed needless escape character `\`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('<a class=\".newCss\" href=\"#\"></a>').appendTo("#myDiv .myCss");
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

From your updated question, I've assumed that your requirement is to copy whatever class `#myDiv` has into the new `<a>` element, regardless of what class that actually is:

```
var myDiv= $("#myDiv");               // find the div
var cls = myDiv.attr('class');        // get its existing class
$('<a>', {href: '#', 'class': cls})   // create the new link with that class
  .appendTo(myDiv);                   // append it
myDiv.removeClass().addClass('test'); // change the div's class
```